# В Android Studio отваливаются библиотеки android.support

Tags: android, android-studio

Вот так выглядит класс в Android Studio:

[image: Среда разработки]

Да, бывает, что при загрузке проекта до его индексации многие классы и методы отображаются красным, но обычно это проходит через минуту-две, после индексирования проекта. А тут я уже и проект собрал, и в эмуляторе запустил (успешно), а библиотеки по-прежнему не видит.

Вот так выглядят импорты. Отвалились только эти два:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во вновь созданном проекте подцепило без проблем.

> gradle.properties:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась вот в чём. От чего и хочу предостеречь начинающих разработчиков.

Заботясь о сохранности кода, я разместил проект в папке Яндекс.Диска. Яндекс.Диск не всегда работает корректно и может перезаписать некоторые файлы, создав дубликат:

```
app.iml

app (2).iml
```

Подцепив не тот `app.iml`, студия не нашла прописанные в ней либы.

Comment: Для сохранности кода придумали различные системы контроля версий, например git.

Comment: Да, это так :) Но я задумался над сохранностью кода до знакомства с git, отсюда Яндекс.Диск.